# ASP.NET MVC 3 ValidationSummary not working with jquery client validatio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have a form that i want to validate ( show validation summary, show validation properties error messages and support jquery client validation ).
Validation summary appears, validation properties error messages appears but when i add

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

for client side validation i get the client validation, i get the validation properties error messages but the validation summary does not appear any more.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 things to verify:

1. The `Html.ValidationSummary` helper call must be **inside** the `<form>`
2. You must pass `false` as argument: `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)`

Example:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)    
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: 1. it is inside <from> tag 2. it works but i don't want to see property errors. is there any way?

Comment: @gigi, no, of course not. Only properties decorated with validation attributes are capable of emitting HTML5 `data-*` attributes that are used by unobtrusive validation. Don't expect the client to be able to generate javascript validation for the server side controls that you are performing inside your controller action.